# Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following code

```
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

And I am getting this error:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/....../public_html/test/basic.rar Folder/global.php on line 355

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `$query` is your actual *query* (such as a `select` string).

You don't pass the query to `mysql_num_rows`, you pass the *result set* that you get back from *executing* the query, something like:

```
$dbconn = mysql_connect ("pax_db_box", "pax", "never_you_mind");
mysql_select_db ("main_db", $dbconn);

$query = "SELECT balance FROM accounts where account_id = '42'";

$result_set = $mysql_query ($query, $dbconn);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows ($result_set);
```

---

You may also want to look into using the newer `mysqli` functions at some point.